# go test some functions/suites from package only

Tags: testing, go

Is it possible to split testing process in go for some package ?
go test package - uses all function Test* in all *_test.go files in package. If you have a lot of tests and try to TDT its rather boring to receive always all test logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See 'go help test' and 'go help testflag'. Quoting from the later:

```
...

-run regexp
    Run only those tests and examples matching the regular
    expression.
...
```